# Conditional Probability and Bayes' Theorem

Tags: probability

If given the following data:

- Percentage of patients who are taking treatments 1,2 and 3:

  > 1. 0.80
  > 2. 0.15
  > 3. 0.05
- Probability of patients responding to treatments 1,2 and 3:

  > 1. 0.03
  > 2. 0.95
  > 3. 0.02

---

- **Q.** What is the average P(R)? 
  **A.** $\dfrac{[(0.80)(0.03) + (0.15)(0.95) + (0.05)(0.02)]}3$, Would this be the correct method for finding the probability of responding to a treatment on average?

  ---
- **Q.** What is the Probability  that a patient was using treatment 3, given that they responded?
  **A.** $T_3$: treatment 3,  $R$: response$$P(T_3|R) = P(R|T_3) \cdot \frac{P(T_3)}{P(R)}$$ where the $P(R|T3) = 0.02$ and $P(R)$: average response from previous question and $P(T_3) = 0.05$?

Comment: This is not understandable. Why don't you show us where you got stuck, and along the way you can explain what the notation and questions mean.

Comment: Ok, apologies..

Comment: @TedShifrin ....

Comment: @Edward I have corrected your post, make sure that your next questions are correctly written from now. For help see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand the phrase "average probability of responding." Presumably you're being asked to find the (net) probability of responding to treatment. So, by Bayes's Formula, this is
\begin{align*}
P(R) &= P(R\big|\text{treatment } 1)P(\text{treatment } 1) + P(R\big|\text{treatment } 2)P(\text{treatment } 2) + P(R\big|\text{treatment } 3)P(\text{treatment } 3) \\
&= (.03)(.8) + (.95)(.15) + (.02)(.05) = .1675
\end{align*}
And, yes, for the second question:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{treatment }3\big|R) &= \frac{P(\text{treatment }3 \text{ and }R)}{P(R)} \\
&= \frac{P(R\big|\text{treatment }3)P(\text{treatment }3)}{P(R)} \\
&= \frac{(.02)(.05)}{.1675}
\end{align*}